# get collection names in a document fiestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an application in flutter. I  am using fiestore in my application. There is some nested path firestore. Actually I want to get collections inside a document. I tried a lot but I failed. This is my database [image]

I want to get the name of these collections inside document 6. This is what I tried until now

```
Future<dynamic> readFire() async {
    final DocumentReference document = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").doc("6");


    await document.get().then((snapshot) async {
      if(snapshot.exists)
        {
          Map doc=snapshot.data();

         print(doc['driver']);
        }
      else
        {
          print("no");
        }
    });
  }
```

But this code is only giving me fields of document not collections. Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: if you want to print with 10 sou have to prnt the id print(doc.id);

Comment: There are no web or client APIs to list Firestore collections.  You will either have to maintain a list in a document you can read, or use a backend API to list them, and have the client call an API endpoint you expose.